# Buffer overflow when running optimized code

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, buffer-overflow

I have a large C program that compresses a file using Huffman encoding. It is compiled with gcc, when I run it with optimizations (-O2 or -O1), and the file I'm compressing is large (16MB doesn't cause a problem, 66MB does), after a few seconds I get a buffer overflow with the following message:

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: ./Huffman terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x741df)[0x7f75eaf681df]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7f75eafffbac]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x10aa70)[0x7f75eaffea70]
./Huffman[0x401da9]
./Huffman[0x401e96]
./Huffman[0x400d75]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f75eaf15ec5]
./Huffman[0x400da0]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00404000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1050895                            /home/shoham/workspace/Huffman/build-Huffman-Desktop-Release/Huffman
00603000-00604000 r--p 00003000 08:07 1050895                            /home/shoham/workspace/Huffman/build-Huffman-Desktop-Release/Huffman
00604000-00605000 rw-p 00004000 08:07 1050895                            /home/shoham/workspace/Huffman/build-Huffman-Desktop-Release/Huffman
01c41000-7fc59000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f756ae98000-7f756aeae000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 135031                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f756aeae000-7f756b0ad000 ---p 00016000 08:05 135031                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f756b0ad000-7f756b0ae000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 135031                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f756b0ae000-7f75eaef4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f75eaef4000-7f75eb0b0000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 144667                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f75eb0b0000-7f75eb2af000 ---p 001bc000 08:05 144667                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f75eb2af000-7f75eb2b3000 r--p 001bb000 08:05 144667                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f75eb2b3000-7f75eb2b5000 rw-p 001bf000 08:05 144667                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
7f75eb2b5000-7f75eb2ba000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f75eb2ba000-7f75eb3bf000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 144663                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
7f75eb3bf000-7f75eb5be000 ---p 00105000 08:05 144663                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
7f75eb5be000-7f75eb5bf000 r--p 00104000 08:05 144663                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
7f75eb5bf000-7f75eb5c0000 rw-p 00105000 08:05 144663                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
7f75eb5c0000-7f75eb5e3000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 144655                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f75eb6b7000-7f75eb7bb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f75eb7dd000-7f75eb7e2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f75eb7e2000-7f75eb7e3000 r--p 00022000 08:05 144655                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f75eb7e3000-7f75eb7e4000 rw-p 00023000 08:05 144655                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
7f75eb7e4000-7f75eb7e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff6c1d4000-7fff6c1f5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff6c1fe000-7fff6c200000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The code I think might be relevant is here, where I read the original file and write the new file:

```
void writeHuffmanTree(HNode * huffmanTree, FILE * read, FILE * write) // reads the input file for which char to write, then searches for it in the huffman tree and writes it into the new file.
{
    Map map;
    unsigned int i, j, currentLocationRead, lengthRead, readBytesNumber, writeBufferIndex;
    unsigned char remainingCodeLength, writeBufferBitIndex, headerSize;
    char * readBuffer, *writeBuffer /* because File IO is slower than Memory IO*/, *header, currentChar;
    currentLocationRead = 0;
    lengthRead = getFileLength(read);
    readBuffer = (char *) calloc(1048576, sizeof(char));
    writeBuffer = (char *) calloc(1048576, sizeof(char));
    if (!readBuffer) quit(7, "writeHuffmanTree() - readBuffer");
    if (!writeBuffer) quit(7, "writeHuffmanTree() - writeBuffer");
    writeBufferIndex = 0; // current location in the array (can't simply ++ it because you may have codes that are 4 in length or something like that
    writeBufferBitIndex = 0; // current free bit index, from here on you can write data.
    map = *getCodeMap(huffmanTree, 0, 0);
    header = createHeader(huffmanTree, FALSE, writeBufferBitIndex, &headerSize);
    fwrite(header, sizeof(char), headerSize, write);
#ifdef debug
    printMap(&map);
#endif
    fseek(read, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while (currentLocationRead < lengthRead)
    {
        readBytesNumber = fread(readBuffer, sizeof(char), 1048576, read); // 1 MB at a time.
        for (i = 0; i < readBytesNumber; i++) // iterate through each character you read from the file
        {
            currentChar = readBuffer[i];
            for (j = 0; j < map.counter; j++) // find said char in the code map to get its code
            {
                if (currentChar == map.character[j]) // when it finds it
                {
                    if ((remainingCodeLength = addCode(writeBuffer, &writeBufferIndex, &writeBufferBitIndex, map.code[j], map.codeLength[j])))
                    { // didn't write the whole code, not enough place in buffer
                        fwrite(writeBuffer, sizeof(char), writeBufferIndex, write); // write the current buffer into the file
                        writeBuffer = (char *) memset(writeBuffer, 0, writeBufferIndex); // reset the buffer
                        writeBufferIndex = 0;
                        addCode(writeBuffer, &writeBufferIndex, &writeBufferBitIndex, map.code[j], remainingCodeLength); //TODO: validate
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        currentLocationRead += readBytesNumber;
#ifdef debug
        printf("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < writeBufferIndex; i++)
            printf("%d, ", writeBuffer[i]);
#endif
    }
    fwrite(writeBuffer, sizeof(char), writeBufferIndex, write); // at the end add whatever remains in the buffer to the file
    if (writeBufferBitIndex != 0)
    {
        fseek(write, 1, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite(&writeBufferBitIndex, 1, sizeof(char), write); // modify the header
    }
    free(writeBuffer);
}
```

EDIT: This is addCode():

```
unsigned char /* remaining code length not inputted */ addCode(char * buffer, unsigned int * currentIndex, unsigned char * currentBitIndex, unsigned char code, unsigned char codeLength)
{
    unsigned char bit;
    unsigned short * twobytes;
    unsigned char bound = codeLength;
    if (*currentBitIndex + codeLength > 8 && *currentIndex >= 1048575) // not enough place for the entire code in the entire buffer
    {
        bound = (*currentBitIndex + codeLength) - (8 - 1 /* (-1) to get index */);
    }
    twobytes = (unsigned short *) (buffer - 1 + *currentIndex); // use a short (2 bytes) to eliminate the problem where you need to change the byte you currently access.
    while (bound > 0)
    {
        bit = READBIT(code, --bound); // TODO: check if use bound or codeLength here
        codeLength--;
        *twobytes = SETBIT(*twobytes, 16 - ++(*currentBitIndex), bit); // (16 - ...) to start from the MSB.
        if (*currentBitIndex == 8) {
            (*currentIndex)++;
            (*currentBitIndex) %= 8;
        }
    }
    return codeLength - bound;
}
```

I'm clueless because it works fine in Debug mode (without optimizations)...
I tried running valgrind on it, but my computer got stuck, I couldn't even move the mouse so I restarted it..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This line looks mighty suspicious `map = *getCodeMap(huffmanTree, 0, 0);`  Why dereference the map pointer?

Comment: @MarkLakata Doesn't solve the problem :(.

Comment: compile it with the optimizations (that cause the error) and with `-g` flag to insert debugging symbols in the executable. Now you will have meaningful names and you can even debug it.

Comment: @bolov Do you know how to do that in Qt Creator? I tried editing the makefile and adding `-g` where all the other gcc options where, but it doesn't seem to change anything when I debug.

Comment: This will help enable the debugger: https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-debugging.html

Comment: @Dogbert That... doesn't really help. If you can find how that'd be nice.

Comment: How are you ensuring you don't overflow `writeBuffer` in `addCode()`?

Comment: @uesp I added the code for `addCode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem...
This line:

```
bound = (*currentBitIndex + codeLength) - (8 - 1 /* (-1) to get index */);
```

Had to be:

```
bound = (*currentBitIndex + codeLength) - 8 - 1 /* (-1) to get index */;
```

Thanks for anoyone who tried to help, you got me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things you might try:

1. Add printf statements with the values of key variables, to make sure that they are what you think they are.  This will also help you figure out where your code is actually crashing.  This is the single best strategy to help you understand what is going on.
2. Understand pointers better -- why are you using the return value of memset?  There's no need for that.  And as another commenter noted, there's no reason to dereference the return value of getCodeMap.  sizeof(char) is defined to be 1.
3. Compile with warnings turned on.  Fix all the warnings.

There are a number of minor issues with the code as well: you don't free readBuffer; you shouldn't use a linear search over the characters (just put them in a 256-element array and do a direct lookup); you should check the return value from fwrite; the fread/fwrite/etc already does buffering, so you don't need a large buffer (and if you care about efficiency, the simplest choice is mmap); you can also declare some of these variables in a narrower scope, which will be cleaner.